# Converting String to Epoch returns constant value over and over

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a json cpp to parse a json and try to graph data. On my x axis i want to have hours and minutes, but when I go to convert them from string "09:30" to epoch time it gives me a constant 21600?
I `cout<<time[i] // the string time` and I get the proper return which is 09:30 - 4:00, but then when I go to convert it

```
time[i] = chartData[i]["minute"].asString();
QString temp = QString::fromStdString(time[i]);
epoch[i] = QDateTime::fromString(temp, Qt::ISODate).toSecsSinceEpoch();
cout << epoch[i] << endl;  //Should cout epoch value
```

I just get the value

```
21600
21600
21600
21600
21600
21600
21600
```

Do you all have any idea what this could be, i believe it should be Qt::ISODate format since its hh:mm:ss but i could be wrong.

Edit:
The json is called by this:

```
    Json::Value chartData = IEX::stocks::intraday(symbolSearchedStd);
    QVector<double> value(390), epoch(390);
    QVector<string> time(390);
```

and the output of json is:

```
"average" : 32.656999999999996,
        "close" : 33.845999999999997,
        "date" : "2020-05-21",
        "high" : 33.912999999999997,
        "label" : "12:06 PM",
        "low" : 33.289999999999999,
        "minute" : "12:06",
        "notional" : 26202.150000000001,
        "numberOfTrades" : 8,
        "open" : 33.020000000000003,
        "volume" : 810
```

Edit 2:

Maincpp

```
    Json::Value chartData = IEX::stocks::intraday(symbolSearchedStd);
    QVector<double> value(390), epoch(390);
    QVector<string> time(390);

    //Reads in data from json(historical data 1 day delayed)
    for(Json::Value::ArrayIndex i = 0 ; i != chartData.size(); i++)
    {

        value[i] = (chartData[i]["average"].asDouble());

        if((value[i] == 0) && (i != chartData.size() - 1))
        {
            value[i] = value[i-1];
        }

        time[i] = chartData[i]["minute"].asString();
        QString temp = QString::fromStdString(time[i]);
        epoch[i] = QDateTime::fromString(temp, Qt::ISODate).toSecsSinceEpoch();
        cout << epoch[i] << endl;


    }
```

Iex Class

```
Json::Value IEX::stocks::intraday(const string &symbol)
{
    Json::Value jsonData;

    if(!isValidSymbol(symbol)){
        cout << "Invalid Symbol! I am returning an uninitialized JSON object!";
        return jsonData;
    }

    string url(IEX_ENDPOINT);
    url+="/stock/"+symbol+"/intraday-prices?token=" + API_TOKEN;
    IEX::sendGetRequest(jsonData, url);
    assert(jsonData.isArray()); //Crash if not an array
    return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: This needs a [example]. Can you please show what's in these variables?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Edited, hope this helps

Comment: The REAL reason we like a good [mre] is it's really hard to make one without answering the question in the process. MRE is a distillation of very powerful debugging techniques and allow you to focus in on the real problem. Often merely removing the noise around the problem is all you need in order to spot the problem. Sometimes you need to dig a bit further and run the MRE in a debugger to see what's going wrong. And if all that fails, you're in a great position to ask well-targeted questions that get answered very quickly.

Comment: Your main.cpp file is missing a main function. When I said "copy and paste" I meant "copy and paste". Don't leave anything to our imaginations. "Here be dragons" - there could be anything in those lines of code you're not showing us, and our imaginations run wild. Read [example] again. The main issue you're having is that you're having trouble converting a string to an epoch time. The IEX api can be taken out and replaced with a hard-coded JSON object.

Comment: A thought experiment: open a new project in your IDE of choice. Copy the code as show in your question into appropriate files in that new project. Do not copy code from your original project to your new project. Does the new project compile? If not, then your example is not complete. Replace function calls with hardcoded data when the function call is not the thing that matters. Remove variables that aren't used to get to the part that's wrong. Make it minimal, but not incomplete. Make it complete, but not all encompassing.

Comment: `"minute" = "12:06"`. `QDateTime::fromString(temp, Qt::ISODate)` expects that the argument is a valid ISO 8601 string. `"12:06"` is not a valid ISO 8601 string. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum

Comment: @JohnFilleau I appreciate your help and sorry about the maincpp, the other main file literally just opens the gui, as for the not valid ISO 8601 then what would "12:06" be then? Im looking at the documentation but it doesnt give me examples

Comment: What documentation are you looking at? You need to look at your IEX documentation to figure out how "12:06" translates to minutes. Maybe that's minutes and seconds? Your guess is as good as mine. What IEX API are you using? I found this one https://github.com/Chudleyj/IEX_CPP_API/ but it doesn't have `IEX::stocks::intraday`, just `IEX::stats::intraday`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Nvm i figured it out, i can just mainly enter the number i one so 28800 for 8 am and just add it by i * 60 each time, thanks again!